# jQuery recognizes wrong ID

Tags: jquery

I have problem, jQuery recognizes wrong ID. When user change their seks(male or female), jQuery will set new ID to four elements(see code below).
Problem is, when I select female sex, jQuery will recognize I'm male. Maybe jQuery sees ID which elements have on page load.

**Four elements**

```
                                    <div class="btn-group _hsync_reg_sex" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <br />
                                    <?php
                                        if($_hsync_rasa == 0)
                                        {
                                        ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default active" id="_hsync_bijelac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="bijelac" autocomplete="off" checked> Bijelac
                                            </label>
                                        <?php 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="_hsync_bijelac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="bijelac" autocomplete="off"> Bijelac
                                            </label>                                                
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                        if($_hsync_rasa == 1)
                                        {
                                        ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default active" id="_hsync_crnac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="crnac" autocomplete="off" checked> Crnac
                                            </label>
                                        <?php 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="_hsync_crnac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="crnac" autocomplete="off"> Crnac
                                            </label>                                                
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                        if($_hsync_rasa == 2)
                                        {
                                        ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default active" id="_hsync_hispanac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="hispanac" autocomplete="off" checked> Hispanac
                                            </label>
                                        <?php 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="_hsync_hispanac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="hispanac" autocomplete="off"> Hispanac
                                            </label>                                                
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                        if($_hsync_rasa == 3)
                                        {
                                        ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default active" id="_hsync_azijac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="azijac" autocomplete="off" checked> Azijac
                                            </label>
                                        <?php 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="_hsync_azijac_m">
                                                <input type="radio" name="_hsync_rasa" id="azijac" autocomplete="off"> Azijac
                                            </label>                                                
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>                                      
                                </div>
```

**jQuery code (when user changes sex)**

```
            $("#_hsync_musko").click(function() {
            var _rasa = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value",_rasa);

            if(_rasa == 0)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_m').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinB; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinB; ?>.png");
            }
            if(_rasa == 1)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_m').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinC; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinC; ?>.png");
            }
            if(_rasa == 2)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_m').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinH; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinH; ?>.png");
            }
            if(_rasa == 3)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_m').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinA; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinA; ?>.png");
            }                   

            $('#_hsync_bijelac_z').attr("id","_hsync_bijelac_m");
            $('#_hsync_crnac_z').attr("id","_hsync_crnac_m");
            $('#_hsync_hispanac_z').attr("id","_hsync_hispanac_m");
            $('#_hsync_azijac_z').attr("id","_hsync_azijac_m");

            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_z').hide();  

            _hsync_prilagodi_rasa_tipke(0, _rasa);
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_zensko").click(function() {
            var _rasa = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value",_rasa);

            if(_rasa == 0)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_z').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinB; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinB; ?>.png");
            }
            if(_rasa == 1)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_z').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinC; ?>");  
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinC; ?>.png");
            }
            if(_rasa == 2)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_z').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinH; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinH; ?>.png");
            }
            if(_rasa == 3)
            {
                $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_z').show();
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value","<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinA; ?>");
                $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinA; ?>.png");
            }

            $('#_hsync_bijelac_m').attr("id","_hsync_bijelac_z");
            $('#_hsync_crnac_m').attr("id","_hsync_crnac_z");
            $('#_hsync_hispanac_m').attr("id","_hsync_hispanac_z");
            $('#_hsync_azijac_m').attr("id","_hsync_azijac_z");

            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_m').hide();

            _hsync_prilagodi_rasa_tipke(1, _rasa);              
        });
```

**When I click on race button**

```
            $("#_hsync_bijelac_m").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","0");
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinB; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_m').show();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_m').hide();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinB; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinB; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");    
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_crnac_m").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","1");
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinC; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_m').show();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_m').hide();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinC; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinC; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_hispanac_m").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","2");               
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinH; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_m').show();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_m').hide();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinH; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinH; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_azijac_m").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","3");
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinA; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_m').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_m').show();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinA; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_muski_skinA; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        });

        $("#_hsync_bijelac_z").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","0");               
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinB; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_z').show();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_z').hide();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinB; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinB; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");   
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_crnac_z").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","1");               
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinC; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_z').show();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_z').hide();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinC; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinC; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_hispanac_z").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","2");
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinH; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_z').show();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_z').hide();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinH; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinH; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        }); 

        $("#_hsync_azijac_z").click(function() {
            $('#_hsync_trenutna_rasa').attr("value","3");               
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin').attr("src","_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_skins/_hsync_skin_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinA; ?>.png");
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_bijelac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_crnac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_hispanac_z').hide();
            $('#_hsync_skin_dio_azijac_z').show();
            $('#skin_slika_'+ $("#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id").val() +'').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img");       
            $('#_hsync_trenutni_skin_id').attr("value", <?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinA; ?>);
            $('#skin_slika_<?php echo $_hsync_zenski_skinA; ?>').attr("class","img-circle _hsync_reg_img_c");
        });
```

Comment: Don't use the same ID, it's just invalid and wrong. Use unique IDs, or replace it with class instead, then select `$('.bijelac')` instead of `$('#bijelac')`

Comment: I don't use same. _hsync_hispanac_m and _hsync_hispanac_z isn't same? ID isn't on input tag, it's on label tag. Look better at code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre code is somewhat confusing, but from what I see you have some radio buttons with the name attribute `name="_hsync_rasa"`, so you can detect any change on these elements using the `change` event:

```
$( "input[name=_hsync_rasa]:radio" ).on('change', function() {
    var selectedRadio = $( "input[name=_hsync_rasa]:radio:checked" );
    alert( 'Selected ID - '  + selectedRadio.attr('id') );
});
```

This is just an example of getting the correct radio element, but because your code is not clear enough (For me), this is the best I can do to help.

You may want to replace the `.on('change', function() {` to `.on('click', function() {` because it might trigger the event twice (One for the unchecked element, and immediately after to the new selected radio). Not sure, but just in case you find that it's happening.

Comment: Everything Works fine. Thanks a lot!